# Square Metre Calculator Help Rounding up square metres

Tags: javascript, jquery, area

I am trying to help a friend fix up his site and they have asked me for help in sorting out a form calculator that calculates square metres... right now it calculates it exactly.  My mate wants it to round up the square metres.   I have no idea about code, is there anyone out there that can help me find a way to round up the square meter please?

Here's what we have so far;

```html
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

    (function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    
    theUnit = 'cms';
        $('#inserted-height').val('');
        $('#inserted-width').val('');

        $('#inserted-height').focus(function(){
            $(this).val('');
    });
        $('#inserted-width').focus(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });

        $('#inserted-height').blur(function(){
        var height = $(this).val();
        if(!checkDigits(height)){
            $(this).focus();
            $('#calculate-button').removeClass("Reset");
            return false;
        }
    });

        $('#inserted-width').blur(function(){
        var width = $(this).val();
        if(!checkDigits(width)){
            $(this).focus();
            $('#calculate-button').removeClass("Reset");
            return false;
        }
    });

    });

        $('#calculate-button').click(function(){

            if ($(this).hasClass("Reset")){

                $('#screen-two').fadeOut(function(){
                    $('#cms-message').fadeIn();
                });

                $(this).removeClass("Reset");
                $(this).val("Submit");
                $('#inserted-height').val('');
                $('#inserted-width').val('');
            return false;
        }
        /* SET SIZES */
        var MIN_SIZE = 20000;
        var MAX_SIZE = 3000000;

        /* FREE SHIPPING */
        

        var currentProductPrice = $('#currentProductPricefromCMS').val();
        var estimatedWidth = $('#inserted-width').val();
        var estimatedHeight = $('#inserted-height').val();
        /* added pre price to calculator */
        var currencySymbol = "AUD$";
        var totalSize = estimatedWidth * estimatedHeight;
        var isInches = false;
        // get the unit type
        var theUnits = $("input[name='unit']:checked").val()
        // console.log(theUnits);

        // boolean for valid inputs
        var valid = false;

        if(theUnit == 'inch') {
            isInches = true;
            totalSize = (estimatedWidth* 2.54) * (estimatedHeight * 2.54);
        } else {
            isInches = false;
        }
        /* WARNING FOR MAX AND MIN SIZES */

        if((totalSize < MIN_SIZE || totalSize > MAX_SIZE) && !isInches){
            alert('Oops... size must be within '+MIN_SIZE/10000+' sqm and '+MAX_SIZE/10000+' sqm. \n Note: 100 cms = 1 Metre.');
            $('#inserted-width').css({'color':' #AA202E'});
            $('#inserted-height').css({'color':' #AA202E'});
            return false;
        }  else {

            if((totalSize < MIN_SIZE || totalSize > MAX_SIZE) && isInches ){
                alert('Oops... size must be within '+MIN_SIZE/10000+' sqm and '+MAX_SIZE/10000+' sqm or approx 27 square feet (MIN) and 323 square feet (MAX). Note: 12 inches = 1 Foot.');
                $('#inserted-width').css({'color':'#AA202E'});
                $('#inserted-height').css({'color':'#AA202E'});
                return false;
            } else {
                valid = true;
            }
        }

        /* DO IT */
        // can only proceed if true
        if(valid){
            //fade in price

            $('#cms-message').fadeOut(function(){
                $('#screen-two').fadeIn();
            });
            $('#calculate-button').val("Reset");
            $('#calculate-button').addClass("Reset");

            /* IF INCHES  */

            if(isInches) {
                // console.log("inches selected");
                var InchesToCms = (totalSize);
                var estimatedPrice = InchesToCms * currentProductPrice;
                // console.log("inches to cms"+totalSize);
                var outputPrice = estimatedPrice / 10000;
                var actualPrice = outputPrice.toFixed(2);
                $('#display-price').val(currencySymbol+actualPrice);
            }
            /* IF CM  */
            else  {
                // console.log("cms selected");
                var estimatedPrice = totalSize * currentProductPrice;
                 /* added for rounding up */
    var totalSize = Math.round(outputPrice); 
                var outputPrice = estimatedPrice / 10000;
              
                var actualPrice = outputPrice.toFixed(2);


                $('.symbol').html("<span>" + currencySymbol + "</span >");
                $('#display-price').val(actualPrice);
            }
            var free_shipping_min = 330;
            /* check if above $400 for actual price */
            if (actualPrice >= free_shipping_min ){
                $(".calculator_disclaimer").html('<b>Price includes <span>FREE</span> shipping</b>');

            } else {

                $(".calculator_disclaimer").html("Price excludes shipping $49.95");
            }

        }

    });

    //REGEX FOR Checking if letters entered.
    function checkDigits(str){

        var intRegex = /[A-z]/;
        if(intRegex.test(str) ) {
            alert('Please enter only numbers');
            return false;
        }  else {
            return true;
        }

    }


    /* RESET BUTTON */
        $('.reset').click(function($){
        totalSize = 0;
        $('#inserted-width').css({'color':'solid 1px #969696'});
        $('#inserted-height').css({'border':'solid 1px #969696'});
       
        $('#inserted-height').val('');
        $('#inserted-width').val('');
    });

    /* TOGGLE BETWEEN INCHES AND CMS */

        $('#radio-inches').click(function($){
        $('.units').val('Inches');
        theUnit = 'inch';
    });

        $('#radio-cms').click(function(){
        $('.units').val('Cms');
        theUnit = 'cms';
    });

    })(jQuery);
// ]]></script>
```

Ok, this is what we have once I have made the changes as advised.

```html
<div class="quick-quote">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home_price_calculator" style="text-align: center;">
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Quick Quote</h3>
Please enter your wall size in centimetres. <!-- HIDDEN FIELDS GETS THE CURRENT PRICE PER SQUARE METRE --> <input id="currentProductPricefromCMS" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="55.000" /> <input id="inserted-width" class="validate" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="length" size="9" value="" /> X <input id="inserted-height" class="validate" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="height" size="9" value="" /> <input id="calculate-button" class="calculate" type="button" value="Submit" name="calculate" /> <!-- <div id="cms-message">Please enter your size in centimetres.</div> --> <input id="display-currency" type="hidden" value="" />$AUD <input id="display-price" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="9" />
<div class="calculator_disclaimer" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
/* SETS CENTIMETRES ONLOAD */
    (function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /* EXECUTION OF PRICING ESTIMATOR */
    theUnit = 'cms';
        $('#inserted-height').val('');
        $('#inserted-width').val('');

        $('#inserted-height').focus(function(){
            $(this).val('');
    });
        $('#inserted-width').focus(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });

        $('#inserted-height').blur(function(){
        var height = $(this).val();
        if(!checkDigits(height)){
            $(this).focus();
            $('#calculate-button').removeClass("Reset");
            return false;
        }
    });

        $('#inserted-width').blur(function(){
        var width = $(this).val();
        if(!checkDigits(width)){
            $(this).focus();
            $('#calculate-button').removeClass("Reset");
            return false;
        }
    });

    });

        $('#calculate-button').click(function(){

            if ($(this).hasClass("Reset")){

                $('#screen-two').fadeOut(function(){
                    $('#cms-message').fadeIn();
                });

                $(this).removeClass("Reset");
                $(this).val("Submit");
                $('#inserted-height').val('');
                $('#inserted-width').val('');
            return false;
        }
        /* GETS INITIAL SIZES */
        var MIN_SIZE = 20000;
        var MAX_SIZE = 3000000;

        /* FREE MIN SHIPPING VARIABLE */
        

        var currentProductPrice = $('#currentProductPricefromCMS').val();
        var estimatedWidth = $('#inserted-width').val();
        var estimatedHeight = $('#inserted-height').val();
        /* added pre price to calculator */
        var currencySymbol = "AUD$";
        /* next line as per advice */
        var totalSize =  Math.ceil((estimatedWidth * estimatedHeight));
        var isInches = false;
        // get the unit type
        var theUnits = $("input[name='unit']:checked").val()
        // console.log(theUnits);

        // boolean for valid inputs
        var valid = false;

        if(theUnit == 'inch') {
            isInches = true;
              /* next line as per advice */
            totalSize = Math.ceil((estimatedWidth * 0.0254) * (estimatedHeight * 0.0254));
        } else {
            isInches = false;
        }
        /* WARNING FOR MAX AND MIN SIZES */

        if((totalSize < MIN_SIZE || totalSize > MAX_SIZE) && !isInches){
            alert('Oops... size must be within '+MIN_SIZE/10000+' sqm and '+MAX_SIZE/10000+' sqm. \n Note: 100 cms = 1 Metre.');
            $('#inserted-width').css({'color':' #AA202E'});
            $('#inserted-height').css({'color':' #AA202E'});
            return false;
        }  else {

            if((totalSize < MIN_SIZE || totalSize > MAX_SIZE) && isInches ){
                alert('Oops... size must be within '+MIN_SIZE/10000+' sqm and '+MAX_SIZE/10000+' sqm or approx 27 square feet (MIN) and 323 square feet (MAX). Note: 12 inches = 1 Foot.');
                $('#inserted-width').css({'color':'#AA202E'});
                $('#inserted-height').css({'color':'#AA202E'});
                return false;
            } else {
                valid = true;
            }
        }

        /* DO IT */
        // can only proceed if true
        if(valid){
            //fade in price

            $('#cms-message').fadeOut(function(){
                $('#screen-two').fadeIn();
            });
            $('#calculate-button').val("Reset");
            $('#calculate-button').addClass("Reset");

            /* IF INCHES SELECTED */

            if(isInches) {
                // console.log("inches selected");
                var InchesToCms = (totalSize);
                var estimatedPrice = InchesToCms * currentProductPrice;
                // console.log("inches to cms"+totalSize);
                var outputPrice = estimatedPrice / 10000;
                var actualPrice = outputPrice.toFixed(2);
                $('#display-price').val(currencySymbol+actualPrice);
            }
            /* IF CM SELECTED */
            else  {
                // console.log("cms selected");
                var estimatedPrice = Math.round((totalSize) * (currentProductPrice));
                var outputPrice = estimatedPrice / 10000;
                
                var actualPrice = outputPrice.toFixed(2);
/* added for rounding up */
    var outputPrice = Math.round(outputPrice);

                $('.symbol').html("<span>" + currencySymbol + "</span >");
                $('#display-price').val(actualPrice);
            }
            var free_shipping_min = 330;
            /* check if above $400 for actual price */
            if (actualPrice >= free_shipping_min ){
                $(".calculator_disclaimer").html('<b>Price includes <span>FREE</span> shipping</b>');

            } else {

                $(".calculator_disclaimer").html("Price excludes shipping $49.95");
            }

        }

    });

    //REGEX FOR Checking if letters entered.
    function checkDigits(str){

        var intRegex = /[A-z]/;
        if(intRegex.test(str) ) {
            alert('Please enter only numbers');
            return false;
        }  else {
            return true;
        }

    }


    /* RESET BUTTON */
        $('.reset').click(function($){
        totalSize = 0;
        $('#inserted-width').css({'color':'solid 1px #969696'});
        $('#inserted-height').css({'border':'solid 1px #969696'});
        /* added by coops 1 Feb 2013 */
        $('#inserted-height').val('');
        $('#inserted-width').val('');
    });

    /* TOGGLE BETWEEN INCHES AND CMS */

        $('#radio-inches').click(function($){
        $('.units').val('Inches');
        theUnit = 'inch';
    });

        $('#radio-cms').click(function(){
        $('.units').val('Cms');
        theUnit = 'cms';
    });

    })(jQuery);
// ]]></script>
<div class="bottom_tab">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bottom_tab" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: "I am fixing up a site for a friend" and "I have no idea about code" in the same paragraph. How is that possible?

Comment: Try a google search for _round up javascript_ - it returns the answer as hit #1. Also, what if the no of m² is 1.01? Do you really want to return 2?

Comment: Round *up*  or just round? E.g does 2.1 become 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend FIRST taking a run at a JS tutorial, given your lack of experience. I admire the confidence, though!

Note that you can use the word `ceil` or the word `round`: ceil will round 1.01, 1.5, etc up to 2, and round will round 1.01, 1.49 etc down to 1 and 1.5, 1.99, etc up to 2.

---

Change the line:

```
var totalSize = estimatedWidth * estimatedHeight;
```

to:

```
var totalSize = Math.round((estimatedWidth / 100) * (estimatedHeight / 100));
```

or:

```
var totalSize = Math.ceil((estimatedWidth / 100) * (estimatedHeight / 100));
```

---

And the line:

```
totalSize = (estimatedWidth* 2.54) * (estimatedHeight * 2.54);
```

to:

```
totalSize = Math.round((estimatedWidth * 0.0254) * (estimatedHeight * 0.0254));
```

or:

```
totalSize = Math.ceil((estimatedWidth * 0.0254) * (estimatedHeight * 0.0254));
```

Comment: thanks Luke - I did try that and got an error regarding the Inches... as it appears most users of his site are from Australia and hence use centimetres.  For the CM's do I simply add the same in for those lines?   JS tutorial is certainly on the cards - thanks heaps for your input.

Comment: You'll have to give much more detail; what's the error? You're wanting to REPLACE those lines, not ADD.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I did replace the code as you said, but inadvertedly made an error in the process.   This time around, I am not getting any error by replacing those lines.  I do need to also have the centimetres section round up as well... I attempted to replace the code in that section of the code but no luck.  Thanks for your time here.

Comment: No luck how?? What went wrong? What did you expect? What happened instead? Exactly what errors appeared, if any? :P

Comment: Ok, I changed the line that said ar estimatedPrice = totalSize * currentProductPrice; to the line var estimatedPrice = Math.round((totalSize) * (currentProductPrice));

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to submit that - but what I did was try and replicate using the information you provided and changed the line as per in the previous comment.   The result was nothing noticeable, no rounding at all.   I tried using the 'ceil' part instead of the round as Luke indicated, also no change.

Comment: Are you sure that is that the line you actually replaced? Because that's the wrong line! :)

Comment: it is?  Truely, this stuff is beyond me, so its no wonder it was the wrong line.  That said I'll give it another whirl after work and see if I can find the right line :)

Comment: Ok, I did that (had already done it as per your previous instructions) however it seems to have no effect on the centimetres i.e. it doesn't seem to be rounding up the square metres for some reason.  I tried both your versions this time around... So if I enter 622x622cm it still gives an exact square metre price.

Comment: Show the complete code with what you've done now, please? In the OP. Keep the original there too, for comparison.

Comment: OK, seems almost ok... Don't think it should be dividing by 10000 when calculating the price, or rounding? Why'd you add that? What are some sample inputs and outputs, please?

Comment: I ain't smart enough to actually add code myself, so no idea why that is there :)  Ok, for some samples, lets say 630 Length x 325 High Calculator gives $1126.13 (exact) and round up to the nearest square metre is $1155.00.    Second sample: 1200 length x 420 high - Calculator = $2772, and round up = $2805       - Hopefully that was what you were after.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what is it actually outputting, rather than the expected?

Comment: sorry the expected result is the round up result in the samples above... and the outputting is the calculator figure

Comment: That is to say, with the current code, you're getting $1126.13, but you're wanting it to say $1155?

Comment: Oh. Right. You didn't actually make the change I told you to!! :P Change line 73 in the second snippet (`var totalSize =  Math.ceil((estimatedWidth * estimatedHeight));`) to `var totalSize =  Math.ceil((estimatedWidth / 100 * estimatedHeight / 100)) * 10000;`.

Comment: You're not using the inches functionality, are you? cm only?

Comment: oh no...damn. I did change it originally, not sure why I changed it back. yeah no inches at all only CM.

Comment: Okay, progress report? I had it working with the above change. Do you have it working? If not, what's happening?

Comment: You Sir, are an absolute legend.  Sorry for testing your patience I clearly missed something - somewhere along the track.  Thank You for saving the day! :)